# Quantized Neural Network Support is gone in TensorFlow 1.0v?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, version, quantization

I'm trying to implement **quantization in neural network** with tensorflow r1.0 and is not working i.e. Bazel BUILD files doesn't find targets and some other files.

I realize that in the version   [r0.9](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.9/tensorflow/contrib/quantization)  the quantization folder in "contrib" is more complete than in   [r1.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/quantization)
In fact there is no quantized operator defined in r1.0.

**There are quantization support only in r0.x versions?**

If there are somebody working with this to give an advice i will be so grateful.

Best regards!

Comment: Is it moved to contrib? Could you check?

Comment: @YaoZhang  In the last version in contrib in the master branch there are not  definition of kernels, maybe in "core" but it doesn't correspond to quantization. May be it is not already finished for this version. I don't know.

Comment: Which tagets and functions/classes you look for are missing?

Comment: Well, all the kernels files and also the files with the definition of operations. Also some targets in BUILD file are missing.

Comment: I identify the problem. It was the fact that quantized kernels definitions have been included in the core with the other kernels. So this issue is solved for me.